# Use maven's "version" property in java and nsis code

Tags: java, nsis, maven-3

we require the software version number of a maven project both in the java code and in the NSIS installer script. Following the DRY principle, the version number should be stored in the maven pom only. What is the best way to get this version number in the Java code as well as in the NSIS script? Updates on the version number should of course be distributed without the developer having to care about it.

The current approach: Wherever the version number is needed, ${"versionNr"} is inserted as a substitute. Then, during the maven build phase, all java and NSIS source files are filtered and the key is replaced by the version number. To avoid changes in the checked in source code, the filtered files are actually copied to a different location not within the scm. Having the original source and the source filtered by maven causes a lot of confusion, which I would like to avoid.

Any hints?

Comment: Thanks for the answers below, but shouldn't there be a really quick and nice way to do this? I mean maven is all about configuration and build stuff, so why is that so complicated to accomplish?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I typically put the version parameter (like ${project.version}) in a properties-file and only apply filtering on that one file in the maven build. Like

```
app.version=${project.version}
```

Then I use this properties file in the code to get the version.

Answer (score 2):

`pom.properties` gets built into JAR file (to `META-INF/maven/<groupId>/<artifactId>/pom.properties`) when the project is packaged up.  It looks something like:

```
#Generated by Maven
#Mon Sep 26 09:03:19 EST 2011
version=1.0-SNAPSHOT
groupId=my.project.group.id
artifactId=my-artifactid
```

You could read this as a resource in your Java code, and use Property API to read the version out.

Not sure whether NSIS scripts can read property files, but according to the [source code of the NSIS plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/nsis-maven-plugin/xref/org/codehaus/mojo/nsis/NsisGenerateProjectMojo.html) it creates a few !defines, including [PROJECT_VERSION](http://mojo.codehaus.org/nsis-maven-plugin/xref/org/codehaus/mojo/nsis/NsisGenerateProjectMojo.html#112) which gets the project version straight from the POM.  Maybe you can use this.